# Dynamically set flex configuration for columns

Tags: javascript, extjs, flexbox

Let's assume I have a window with a grid inside.
I code this via ExtJS, version 5.1.3.
This grid has four columns and the last one has the property `flex:1`.
Perfect, everything is aligned.
Now I have the possibility to hide the last column. As the other columns do not have the property `flex`, the grid is cut inside the window.

The window looks then similar to the last screenshot in this [link](http://extjs-intro.blogspot.co.at/2014/04/extjs-grid-panel-column-resize.html).

Now my question: Is it somehow possible to define kind of a temporary `flex` property if no column with `flex` is available and then reset as soon as it is again?

Comment: why can't you put a flex on all the columns ? Or remove the flex all together and use autoWidth

Comment: @BhandariS I actually do not want to have a flex property on every column as it resizes based on the content. Does autoWidth calculate with the width of the column header or the cell width itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `forceFit : true` configuration in grid object.

```
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        data: [{
            name: 'Lisa',
            email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-111-1224'
        }, {
            name: 'Bart',
            email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1234'
        }, {
            name: 'Homer',
            email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1244'
        }, {
            name: 'Marge',
            email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
            phone: '555-222-1254'
        }]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        forceFit : true,
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Phone',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }],
        height: 500,
        width: 600,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```